# Spock groovy - how to mock methods in same class?

Tags: java, groovy, mocking, mockito, spock

How to mock the private method and method in a different class in the test class?

```java
class MyClass {
    private final Retriever<ScoreData> retriever;
    private DataStore<Model> dataStore;
    private String gameName;

    public void MyClass(Retriever<ScoreData> retriever, DataStore<Model> dataStore, String gameName) {
        this.retriever = retriever;
        this.dataStore = dataStore;
        this.gameName = gameName;
    }

    public void process(GameHolder<G> games) {
        // Business Logic
        for (Game<G> game : games){
        Integer score = game.getScore();
        Integer playerId = game.getPlayerId();
        Integer finalScore = getScore(game);
        computeScore(score, finalScore);
        }
    }

    private Integer computeScore(int score, int finalScore) {
        // Runs some business logic and returns O3
        return score + finalScore;
    }

    private Integer getScore(Game game) {
        // Runs some business logic and returns O3
        String dbName = game.getDbName();
        DBRetriever ret = new DBRetriever(dbName)
        if (dbName.equals("gameDB"){
            return ret.getFinalScore(dbName);
        }
        return -1;
    }

}
```

Below is my current implementation for Spock and I am not sure how to implement the mocking for objects.

```
@Subject
def obj

def "this is my test"(){
    given:
    Object1 obj1 = Mock(Object1)
    Object2 obj2 = Mock(Object2)
    Object3 obj3 = Mock(Object3)

    def myClassObject = new MyClass(obj1, obj2, obj3)

    when:
    myClassObject.process(new Object4())

    then:
    1 * getScore()
    1 * computeScore()

}
```

How can I mock the computeScore and getScore functions and how can I assign the initial values for objects obj1, obj2, obj3?

Note: I am only trying to test `process()` method here. But process method is calling a private method from inside. I want to be able to return a mock value for private method rather than executing the private method.

Edit: Retriever and DataStore are interfaces and their respective implementations are ScoreData and Model.

Comment: There is no `getValue()` method in your code. Please edit the question and add the method. I hope it is public because a class with only private methods does not make much sense as no other class can call and interact with it. Even if it was technically possible, good testing only tests the public interface of a class. If you find it difficult to cover your private methods via testing public ones, something is probably wrong with your code. I can tell you after you added the missing method. BTW, `process()` is missing a return type. No pseudo code, please.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out. I have made the edits. This is more for a sense to understand how to mock a method in the same class and also mock an object of class "MyClass" with constructor args using Spy()

Comment: @kriegaex I have added more details to the question. Please let me know if you need more information.

Comment: Your code does not compile. What is `String S`? And why do you assign the results calculated in `process(..)` to local variables and never use them? And why are methods `getScore()` and `computeScore()` defined in `MyClass`, but your code calls them as if they were methods of `Object1`? Please fix your code so it makes logical sense and is no pseudo code. If you want to abstract sample classes from your original code, at least be so kind as to make sure they run and also provide the dependencies `Object{1-4}` as dummy classes. Compile and run your own code before you ask me questions about it.

Comment: Aha, you edited your question multiple times. Now I can see that the two methods are actually defined in `MyClass` and no longer called on `o1` like before, which made no logical sense. But now the test does not make sense anymore. Why would you mock or stub the class under test, only in order to check later that the stubbed methods were indeed called? This kind of test does not have any added value, but of course you can do it. And why would you over-specify the test to check that private methods were called? We just talked about the fact that you should not test private methods directly.

Comment: @kriegaex I agree that we should not test private methods directly. What I am wondering is, when I call the public method, it is in return calling a private method. Now the problem I am trying to solve is, I don't care if it calls the private method. But since it is already built into the code logic (that is a public method inside is calling a private method), the values returned by private method may vary. I just want to assign a constant return value from the private method for testing the public method.

Comment: Make your injected mocks return the right values so the private methods' return values will become predictable too. Just excluding them from running in a test is the opposite of what a test wants. But we are talking about hidden code. The code you have difficulty with is not part of your question - why?

Comment: Hm, now again you completely changed your sample code. It is difficult to keep track and answer the question like this, but I will try. BTW, your code still does not compile. A constructor does not return `void`, for example. Its implicit return type is the type it is constructing, hence the name constructor. Also your method `void process(..)` is trying to return something, which makes no sense. Does your own code even compile? You cannot test something that does not even compile.

Comment: Apologies. Pretty new to it and still learning. But following the pattern, I got a null pointer exception in computescore method as it is initializing a new object there. Yes my own code compiles.

Comment: Changed it. Void process doesn't return anything. It just computes score.

Comment: I spent way too much time here, trying to fix your code, trying to explain and point out things. But your new version of the code has so many problems and unknown classes and. If you are unable to produce a real [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (maybe sharing it on GitHub), I will not answer any more questions. It is impossible to tell you how to test code which does not even compile due to syntax errors and lots of missing dependencies. "I cannot see the forest for all the trees", as we say in German. Looking forward to a **real** MCVE.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Note: I am only trying to test `process()` method here. But process method is calling a private method from inside. I want to be able to return a mock value for private method rather than executing the private method.

You should not do that because `MyClass` is your class under test. You cannot cover the logic inside the private methods with tests if you stub them. Instead, you should make sure that the injected mocks behave the way you want them to (via stubbed methods) if they are used inside those private method. Unfortunately you decided not to show that crucial part of your code even though the exact answer depends on it. Instead you replaced them with comments "some business logic", which is not very helpful because your business logic is what you want to test. You don't want to stub it out.

---

***So please don't do what I am showing you here, I am answering only because you asked.***

In order to stub a method it must not be private because spies, mocks or stubs technically are always subclasses or the originals and subclasses cannot inherit or even call private methods. Thus, you need to make the methods protected (so subclasses can use or override them) or package-scoped. I recommend the former.

But you cannot use a normal mock or stub as a stand-in for your class under test because you only want to stub out part of the business logic (your two methods in question), not the whole logic (you want to keep `process()`). Thus, you need a partial mock. For this purpose you can use a spy.

**Dummy dependency classes:**

```java
package de.scrum_master.stackoverflow.q60103582;

public class Object1 {}
```

```java
package de.scrum_master.stackoverflow.q60103582;

public class Object2 {}
```

```java
package de.scrum_master.stackoverflow.q60103582;

public class Object3 {}
```

```java
package de.scrum_master.stackoverflow.q60103582;

public class Object4 {}
```

**Class under test:**

```java
package de.scrum_master.stackoverflow.q60103582;

public class MyClass {
  private Object1 o1;
  private Object2 o2;
  private Object3 o3;

  public MyClass(Object1 o1, Object2 o2, Object3 o3) {
    this.o1 = o1;
    this.o2 = o2;
    this.o3 = o3;
  }

  public void process(Object4 o4) {
    System.out.println("process - business Logic");
    Object2 result = getScore("dummy ID");
    Object3 obj = computeScore(result);
  }

  protected Object3 computeScore(Object2 result) {
    System.out.println("computeScore - business logic");
    return o3;
  }

  protected Object2 getScore(String id) {
    System.out.println("getScore - business logic");
    return o2;
  }
}
```

**Spock test:**

```groovy
package de.scrum_master.stackoverflow.q60103582

import spock.lang.Specification

class MyClassTest extends Specification {
  def "check main business logic"(){
    given:
    Object1 obj1 = Mock()
    Object2 obj2 = Mock()
    Object3 obj3 = Mock()

    MyClass myClass = Spy(constructorArgs: [obj1, obj2, obj3])

    when:
    myClass.process(new Object4())

    then:
    1 * myClass.getScore(_) //>> obj2
    1 * myClass.computeScore(_) //>> obj3
  }
}
```

Here you can see how to check interactions on the spy. But note that `computeScore(_)` and `getScore(_)` will still be executed, as you can see in the console log:

```
process - business Logic
getScore - business logic
computeScore - business logic
```

If you uncomment the end of the last two lines of code

```groovy
    1 * myClass.getScore(_) >> obj2
    1 * myClass.computeScore(_) >> obj3
```

you will actually avoid the two (protected) methods from being executed altogether and replace them by stub results. The console log will change to:

```
process - business Logic
```

But I am saying it again: Don't do this. Instead make sure your injected mocks show the right behaviour so you can actually execute the methods in your class under test. This is what testing is about, isn't it?

Comment: This may be a dumb question, but how to inject mocks? Reason I am asking is, the private method is calling a DB service. So I would not want to execute the logic for calling a DB service. I am trying to learn and so I am asking these questions.

Comment: I have additional information in the question. After trying the answer provided in the comment, I am receiving a null pointer exception at getScore().

Comment: I received a null pointer exception at the line "DBRetriever ret = new DBRetriever(dbName)" in the edited program, following the statement "1 * myClass.getScore(_) >> None"

Comment: That's a typical case of untestable code. Inside the method, you are creating a dependency, assigning it to a local variable. You got to refactor for `DBRetriever` to be injectable via constructor, method parameter or setter. The DB connection should be mocked, but that is only possible if you can somehow inject a mock. Your inability to test the code tells you to refactor it.